# Change reading order of elements within a focusable ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, talkback, accessibility

I have some screens in my app where TalkBack does not infer the correct reading order. According to the documentation, I can use [`android:accessibilityTraversalAfter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:accessibilityTraversalAfter) and friends to alter the reading order. But it does not work for me for elements within a focusable `ViewGroup` that should be read together.

The entire layout looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@id/before"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@id/before"
        android:text="Before"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/after"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@id/after"
        android:text="After"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/before"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It renders `After` in the middle of the screen, `Before` at the bottom. I want TalkBack to treat the entire screen as a single contiguous element, hence I set `android:focusable` to `true`. By default, TalkBack reads: *"After, before"*. But I want it to read *"Before, after"*. Although I've added `android:accessibilityTraversalBefore` and `android:accessibilityTraversalAfter`, it still reads *"After, before"*. That's the output of the Node Tree Debugging:

```
TreeDebug: (-2147455381)429.FrameLayout:(0, 0 - 1080, 1920):A
TreeDebug:   (30189)429.TextView:(42, 101 - 397, 172):TEXT{My Application}:A:supportsTextLocation
TreeDebug:   (31150)429.ViewGroup:(0, 210 - 1080, 1794):Fa:focusable:accessibilityFocused
TreeDebug:     (33072)429.TextView:(499, 951 - 581, 1002):TEXT{After}:A:supportsTextLocation
TreeDebug:     (32111)429.TextView:(485, 1743 - 595, 1794):TEXT{Before}:A:supportsTextLocation
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just for completeness: `minSdkVersion` is 26, `targetSdkVersion` is 29.

Comment: Can you verify, that you see this happening in a blank project with that layout? Or are you able to reproduce the issue only within your app/your setup?

Comment: This layout is pulled from an empty sample app created with AS 3.5 using the blank template. Activity is empty except `onCreate()` that does a `super()` call and `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've dug into the problem and found out following: `accessibilityTraversalBefore` and `accessibilityTraversalAfter` flags in deed take effect, but only for what they are intended for - they are intended for Accessibility Service app (e.g. Talkback). In other words if you remove `focusable` attribute from root layout you'll see that navigation is correct.

But those flags do not affect as to how `AccessibilityNode` is constructed for root `ViewGroup`. As can be seen in [sources of `ViewGroup#onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#3673) the actual text construction logic does **not** regard how children construct their navigation using upper mentioned flags.

In order to solve the problem I've removed excessive flags from layout xml as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:text="Before"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/after"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:text="After"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/before"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And inside the host activity/fragment:

```
val root = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.root)

ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(root, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
        host: View?,
        info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat?
    ) {
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        root.children.forEach { view ->
            val label = if (view is TextView) view.text else ""
            stringBuilder.append("$label, ")
        }

        info?.text = stringBuilder.toString()
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
    }
})
```

This will result in the desired outcome: Talkback will pronounce *"Before, After"*.

Unfortunately, this is an error prone code, meaning that if you restructure the view hierarchy in a way, that order of children gets swapped then this node text construction logic will become broken. Nevertheless, I couldn't come up with a better solution and cannot see it's possible to instruct parent to regard child ordering flags (based on sources).

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth investigation. `focusable` is primarily there to help with keyboard navigation. That it has an effect on TalkBack is a bonus considering that `screenReaderFocusable` is only available on API 28. But even with `screenReaderFocusable` alone it doesn't read `before` before `after`. Therefore I find the first paragraph confusing. What's the purpose of those attributes if they don't affect the `AccessibilityNode` of the `ViewGroup`? But thanks a lot for confirming that I have to construct the text hierarchy myself.